# Polymer 2.0 service worker custom events

Tags: polymer, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, polymer-2.x

I'm new to Polymer 2.0 and also to service workers. However, if I build via Polymer there is a service-worker.js written. Everything works fine until this point.

I would like to add my own events to the service worker. Like a 'sync' event for syncing with pouchdb.

I added `importScripts: ['sw.js']` to the `sw-precache-config.js` file. This results in a code line `importScripts("sw.js");` within the `service-worker.js` file.

My idea was now to add my 'sync' event to `sw.js` but the event does not after coming back online. Do I do it wrong? Did I miss something? Is there a better way?

**EDIT:**

On a button click the following function is called:

```
function onMessageSend(message){
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
  registration.sync.register('outbox').then(function() {
  console.info('success');},function() {
  console.info('no success');});});
}
```

The sync event within the `sw.js` looks like this:

```
self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {
   console.log("a sync catched");
   if (event.tag === "outbox") {
      console.log("is my sync");
      event.waitUntil(fetch("http://website.com/otherthings",{ mode: 'no-cors'})
      .then(function(response) {
      console.log("ok, sent");})
      .catch(console.error));
}});
```

After calling `onMessageSend()` I see that `waitUntil` tries to fetch the website but fails if offline. That is wanted.

But shouldn't the sync event beeing fired also when there is a change from offline to online state after it failed? This does not happen at all.

**EDIT2:** My computer is connected via LAN. The sync event is firing immediatly, independent of the connection state.
There is something wrong.

**EDIT3:** Removing the catch from the waitUntil did not help.

Comment: what is your work-flow to test `sync` event in `sw.js`. ..? which browser r  u using...?

Comment: Latest chrome canary. I'm using chrome devtools->application->service worker->offline. From what I understood, the sync should fire after coming back from offline. Am I right?

Comment: not sure but, if there is nothing to sync then event won't fire. The best way is `==> go offline ==> create record ==> exit application ==> go online ==> check your db for record.`  if your db is updated with new record means `sync` event if working.

Comment: I added further information to the question. I guess I got it wrong but the sync is not firing after emulating offline state via chrome.